# Output of sawtooth generator circuit always 0V in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to simulate a basic sawtooth generating circuit using an opamp integrator and a Schmitt trigger. However, for some reason, all the output voltages in the following circuit are always 0V:

[image]

I am using the standard parameters for the OpAmp (Avol=1Meg GBW=10Meg Slew=10Meg).

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Try this ".tran 1 uic"

Comment: Thanks very much, the ".tran 1 uic" did indeed solve the problem and the circuit worked as expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As user G36 mentioned, this problem can be solved by adding the `uic` argument to the simulation command (e.g. use `.tran 10 uic` as a simulation command):

[image]

Comment: Also adding `ic=1` (or some value) to the capacitor, or making even only one of the supplies a ramp (say `pwl 0 0 1m 15`), or adding `startup` instead of `uic`. For the first two, `.ic` is not needed, but it is for the last one. BTW, you can accept your own answer (the check mark). Welcome to the site. (edit) You can also use only that `.ic` but with a higher voltage, e.g. `.ic v(out)=10`, then none of the other solutions would be needed.